# How to connect two VM (postgreSQL and tomee) using Vagrant?

Tags: java, linux, postgresql, vagrant, apache-tomee

I'm trying to build a virtual environment with Virtualbox and Vagrant.
The goal is to be able to access from pc browser to an app running on virtual machine 'server', that interacts with virtual machine 'db'.

I managed to create the virtual machines.

The first one is up with Apache Tomee running and i can access it through my browser. It works correctly.

The second one is up with Postgres running and i can access it through my browser. It works correctly too.

When I try to connect VM 'server' with 'db' I get an http 500 error (only when i try some db operation with the app), in particular:

```
"Connection to localhost:2222 refused. Check that the hostname and port
```

```
 are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
```

```
 javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:229)"
```

I tested the two machines from pc browser and they works correctly (in fact in db machine I see objects added).

This is Vagrantfile:

```
config.vm.define "server" do |node|
    node.vm.hostname = "server"    
    node.vm.network "private_network", ip: "10.12.1.101",       virtualbox__intnet: true

  [...]

    node.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 22, host: 2211, id: 'ssh', auto_correct: true
    node.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8080, host: 2212

    node.ssh.forward_agent = true

[...]
 end

config.vm.define "client" do |node|
    node.vm.hostname = "client"    
    node.vm.network "private_network", ip: "10.12.1.201", virtualbox__intnet: true

   [...]

    node.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 22, host: 2221, id: 'ssh', auto_correct: true
    node.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 5432, host: 2222

end
```

In file tomee.xml present in apache-tomee/conf I specified the same code for db connection I use in testing (that works correctly out of virtual environment)

```
<tomee>
  <Resource id="PostgreSQL Database" type="DataSource">
          JdbcDriver   org.postgresql.Driver
      JdbcUrl  jdbc:postgresql://localhost:2222/music
      UserName     postgres
      Password     postgres
      JtaManaged      true
      DefaultAutoCommit   false
    </Resource>
</tomee>
```

On db VM i modified both postgresql.conf and pg_hba.conf adding

> listen_addresses = '*'

in the first and

> host    all             all              0.0.0.0/0              md5

in the second. I don't understand why when tomee is running on my pc I can access both 2 VM, but 'server' can't communicate with 'db'.

This is the output of "sudo netstat -tulpn | grep postgres" on db VM

tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5432      0.0.0.0:*      LISTEN   5743/postgres
tcp6       0      0 :::5432             :::*         LISTEN  5743/postgres

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `localhost` to the IP of the machine hosting the VMs (you have port forwarding for the *guests* from the *host*). Or use [bridged networking](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_bridged) and connect from client to server directly.

Comment: I tried to do it, but the error it's more or less the same. (if you refer to tomee.xml file). 
>"Connection to 10.12.1.201:2222 refused. Check that the hostname and port

Comment: If you're connecting to the guest directly, use the real port; the forwarded port is for connecting to the *host* (the machine running your virtualboxes).